# Rails - how to fetch random records from an object?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, random

I am doing something like this:

```
data = Model.where('something="something"')
random_data = data.rand(100..200)
```

returns:

```
NoMethodError (private method `rand' called for #<User::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007fbab27d7ea8>):
```

Once I get this random data, I need to iterate through that data, like this:

```
random_data.each do |rd|
  ...
```

I know there's a way to fetch random data in MySQL, but I need to pick the random data like 400 times, so I think to load data once from database and 400 times to pick random number is more efficient than to run the query 400 times on MySQL.

But - how to get rid of that error?

```
NoMethodError (private method `rand' called for #<User::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007fbab27d7ea8>):
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: How many rows has that table in total? Are the primary ids in that table complete or are there gaps (did you delete records)?

Answer (score 2):

I would add the following scope to the model (depends on the database you are using):

```
# to model/model.rb
# 'RANDOM' works with postgresql and sqlite, whereas mysql uses 'RAND'
scope :random, -> { order('RAND()') }
```

Then the following query would load a random number (in the range of 200-400) of objects in **one query**:

```
Model.random.limit(rand(200...400))
```

If you really want to do that in Rails and not in the database, then load all records and use `sample`:

```
Model.all.sample(rand(200..400))
```

But that to be slower (depending on the number of entries in the database), because Rails would load all records from the database and instantiate them what might take loads of memory.

Comment: But this mean I always get 400 records, right? I'd need a random count of results (let's say between 200 and 400). And also, there's 400 queries on database, but in the other approach, there's only one record and 400 times ran the method for grabbing random records. Just wondering what's more efficient.

Comment: ORDER BY can negatively influence query performance on large database tables.  I wouldn't use this in production code.

Comment: @user984621: I updated my answer. It would only query the database once.

Comment: @mcfinnigan: Ordering in the database is definitely faster than loading all records into memory first (like the suggested in the question). Especially for bigger databases. But you are right this might not be a good idea for a table with millions on lines.

Answer (score 0):

Use `data.sample(rand(100..200))` 
for more info why rand is not working, read here https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994-ruby-on-rails/tickets/4555

Comment: Hmm.. I am trying that approach, but got this error: `TypeError (no implicit conversion of Range into Integer):`

Comment: you can try data.sample(rand(10..100))

Answer (score 0):

Another way, which is not DB specific is :

```
def self.random_record
  self.where('something = ? and id = ?', "something", rand(self.count))
end
```

The only things here is - 2 *queries* are being performed. `self.count` is doing one query - `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM models` and the other is your actual query to get a *random* record.

Well, now suppose you want `n` random records. Then write it like :

```
def self.random_records n
  records = self.count
  rand_ids = Array.new(n) { rand(records) }
  self.where('something = ? and id IN (?)', 
             "something", rand_ids )
end
```

Answer (score 0):

It really depends how much effort you want to put into optimizing this, because there's more than one solution. Here's 2 options..

Something simple is to use `ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 400` to randomly select 400 items.

Alternatively, just select everything under the moon and then use Ruby to randomly pick 400 out of the total result set, ex:

```
data = Model.where(something: 'something').all # all is necessary to exec query
400.times do
  data.sample # returns a random model
end
```

I wouldn't recommend the second method, but it should work.